# mp3 files wont play on IE11 in html5 game but play in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, createjs

I have a js game that will not play my audio files in IE11. The audio works fine in chrome. What am I doing wrong?

I used audition to convert the wavs to mp3's. It said it was converting them as lossy or lossless. Not sure what that means.

Link to game.
https://dev.fvtclearninginnovations.com/wisconline/arcade/games/career-clusters/agriculture-food-natural-resources/105/my-great-game

I read this similar post and tried a few of the fixes that were relevant my my case with no luck. [mp3 audio works in all browsers but not IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192140/mp3-audio-works-in-all-browsers-but-not-ie9)

```
    var assets = [
        { id: "BackGround", src: assetsPath + "sequenceBlackBackground.png" },
        { id: "start_button", src: assetsPath + "SequencePlayButton.png" },
        { id: "clockBack", src: assetsPath + "clockBack.png" },
        { id: "clockHand", src: assetsPath + "clockHand.png" },
        { id: "levelUp", src: assetsPath + "Levelup.jpg" },
        { id: "GameOverIcon", src: assetsPath + "gameovericon.png" },
        { id: "GameOver", src: assetsPath + "GameOver.mp3" },//GameOver.ogg
        { id: "level1_Audio", src: assetsPath + "level1.mp3" },
        { id: "level2_Audio", src: assetsPath + "level1.mp3" },
        { id: "level3_Audio", src: assetsPath + "level3.mp3" },
        { id: "levelup", src: assetsPath + "level-up.mp3" },
        { id: "click", src: assetsPath + "click.mp3" }
    ];


        function playLevelAudioClip() {
            if (level == 1) {
                createjs.Sound.play("level1_Audio");
            } else if (level == 2) {
                createjs.Sound.play("level2_Audio");
            } else if (level == 3) {
                createjs.Sound.play("level3_Audio");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mp3 audio works in all browsers but not IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192140/mp3-audio-works-in-all-browsers-but-not-ie9)

Comment: I read that post and i couldn't see a solution that i could use. Am i over looking something?

Comment: I think so... It is still a duplicate... I think

Comment: I re-read the post. I have my play audio box checked in internet options. I don't know where Id add preload="auto" in my code above. The other post talk about editing the html doc which in mine i just load my canvas theres no other code. Still lost.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the output from the console in IE11 web developer tools?

Also test the mp3 file locally in IE11. Right click the file and open with IE11 to make sure that the file loads in the browser.

This will help to locate the problem.

Comment: After some testing i figured out its not the code its my pc. The page plays fine on other pcs just not mine.

Comment: That's great. Hope I helped in some way.